# How to show two continuous spaces in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

**UPDATE: Both ways from Chris and Mark work.**

I am using Angular 2. I try to show two continuous spaces between `a` and `b`in the page. I've tried all of these, but none of them works:

```
{{text}}

text = "a\00a0\00a0b";
text = `a\00a0\00a0b`;
text = "a&nbsp;&nbsp;b";
text = `a&nbsp;&nbsp;b`;
text = "a  b";
text = `a  b`;
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Bind to DOM property `innerHTML` instead of DOM property `textContent` (which is what `{{}}` binds to):

```
<span [innerHTML]="text"></span>

text = "a&nbsp;&nbsp;b";
```

Comment: In version 6.0.0 I found that you have to add single quotes around the text string since it otherwise assumes the whole thing is a variable. You also can't take the square brackets from around innerHTML as that complains for a different reason. So basically ```text = "'a&nbsp;&nbsp;b'"``` is what worked for me.

Answer (score 25):

I believe you're getting this because of the nature of html stripping spaces.

You could perhaps use the `white-space: pre` css property on whatever element you are rendering that text.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.text = 'a      b';
}
...
<p style="white-space: pre">{{text}}</p>
```

I don't know alot about your application, but perhaps this will suffice.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dvrorwko/1/)

Comment: But he said he tried `&nbsp;`s, which aren't stripped by HTML.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, until I tried it locally. The above is the only I got to work. It might suffice for OP, so worth trying I suppose.

Comment: Fair enough.  You might want to show the value assigned to `text`, so people don't have to click through to the demo.

Comment: Thank you, @Chris! Your `style="white-space: pre"` way is also working in Angular 2.

Comment: Glad you found it useful!

Comment: Worked for me :)

Comment: This worked for me as expected. Thank you for suggetion.

Answer (score 13):

use `'&#160;'` instead of `'&nbsp;'` in template.